# Variable label and title not showing up in r beanplot or boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, axis-labels

I am making a beanplot in the beanplot library in r. I get no errors, but the title is not showing up and 1 of the 3 grouping variable labels is not showing up. Here is the code:

```
memorydata$Condition[memorydata$Condition==1] <- "Anx"
memorydata$Condition[memorydata$Condition==2] <- "Emp"
memorydata$Condition[memorydata$Condition==3] <- "Dom"

memorydata$Condition <- factor(memorydata$Condition)

install.packages("beanplot")
library("beanplot")
beanplot(memorydata$Memory_Bias~memorydata$Condition, xlab="Condition",
ylab="Proportion Correct", ylim="0-1", fill=c("blue", "yellow",  
"green"), show.names="TRUE", title("Memory Bias per Condition"))
```

Can anybody point out an error that is leading to these things now showing up? "Dom" is the group that does not show up.

Thanks!

Comment: For the title try using `main = "Memory Bias Per Condition"`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Still no luck on the missing group. @Mako212

Comment: Regarding DOM,  try deleting your ylim parameter.

Comment: hm..that made no difference. thanks though! @G5W